# Remove property in Meteor user

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor app where I have users who can select favorite cards etc. I store favorite cards in Meteor.user().profile.favorites[]. This is an array with cards (objects). I can't seem to find a way how to remove one from this array.

Comment: Use $pull when updating (you need the whole favorites object which is to be removed)

Comment: thanks. This works :)

Comment: @Todilo you should post this as a proper answer, preferebly with the relevant code. and Wolf you should then mark that as the accepted answer. This is to ensure stack overflow can operate as it is meant to be and other devs looking for similar solutions can know that this has been solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$pull is used to remove an item from an array, you need to give it the exact document.

```
Users.update(id, $pull : { profile : { favorites : { favorite } } });
```